# How to layout a RelativeLayout in a custom view's onLayout function?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am implementing a custom view, and I have three subviews that I can't get to appear. It seems like the subviews aren't showing; I have set the backgrounds to be red, blue, and green for now to show where I have made set the layout, which is shown in the picture.

I need the subviews to be shown so that the view is complete.

This is the code I'm using in onLayout for the subviews:

```
    backButton.layout(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + seventhWidth, topOffset + seventhWidth);
    backButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    nextButton.layout((int) (leftOffset + calendarWidth - seventhWidth), topOffset, (int) (leftOffset + calendarWidth), topOffset + seventhWidth);
    nextButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    monthContainerLayout.layout(leftOffset + thirdWidth, topOffset, (int) Math.round(leftOffset + 2 * thirdWidth), topOffset + seventhWidth);
    monthContainerLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

This is the layout XML for the red square:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what the code and layout currently produces (my custom view is only the calendar):

[image]

Not sure if this matters, but this is how I'm making the views:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_back, this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_forward, this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_header, this);
        backButton = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
        nextButton = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.forward);
        monthContainerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
```

Comment: and what did you actually wanted?

Comment: There should be an image in the middle of the squares, and a textview in the center of the middle (blue) relativelayout.

Comment: sorry for the delay but where is the textviews and image you are talking about i do not see its code here

Comment: There is an ImageView inside the RelativeLayout, and it's not showing up (see the XML). It's OK though, I solved this already by manually drawing the bitmap onto the canvas.

Comment: okay sir -- sorry for not being helpful